# Unity particles 2d wont rotate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particles, particle-system

i am trying to make the particles come out facing at the angle OPOSITE of where the bullet was aiming but....nope, they always come out at the same angle, could anyone explain why?

```
  if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
    {
        float trialboo = this.transform.rotation.z;
        GameObject richochet = Instantiate(ricochetParticles, particleSpawnPoint.position, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f));
        ParticleSystem richochetps = richochet.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

      var shape = richochetps.shape;
        var rotationpower = this.transform.rotation.z- 45;
       shape.rotation = new Vector3(0f, 0f, rotationpower);
        richochetps.Play(); shape.rotation = new Vector3(0f, 0f, rotationpower);
        print("winning");
        // Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Way**: Place the `particle` as child of an `empty object` then rotate parent.

Comment: id love to do that, but that way ill never learn